# How to correctly upload a file using FormData with Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, form-data

I would like to upload an image by sending a FormData payload to a HTTP URL. The sending is right but every time I try to open the image uploaded the file is damaged. I'm using Vuetify as the UI library so that's why I use [`v-file-input`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/file-inputs/#file-inputs) instead of `input type="file"`.

Here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-file-input label="Select a file" accept="image/*" v-model="myFile">
      File to upload to S3
    </v-file-input>
    <v-btn class="ma-2" color="secondary" @click="uploadFile()">
      Upload
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myFile: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uploadFile() {
      let formData = new FormData()
      formData.append("files", this.myFile, this.myFile.name);

      this.$http.put(myURL, formData)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you show your server-side code, sounds like your not saving it correctly (especially since your button says upload to S3)

Comment: I don't have server-side code as I'm using S3 as the destination target to upload my file. I'm using a pre-signed URL to do it.

Comment: What do you see in your network tab? The response looks fine?

Comment: your want to debug if its `files` or `file`, and find out what's in the corrupted file by opening it in a hex editor

Comment: @kissu - Yes the response is fine and I also see my file inside the S3 bucket

@LawrenceCherone - I just want to upload one file. When I open the corrupted image inside a hex editor I have `Content-Disposition: form-data;` `name="files";` `filename="mykey.jpg"` `Content-Type: image/jpeg` before the raw data of the image.